# Ordering by complex structure in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called Event that has many EventRegistrations, which belongs to a person.
Also the EventRegistration has many EventAtendees, which belongs to a person too.

I want to order in Rails all the people related to a event, which means:
 - Person associated to an event registration
 - Person associated to an event atendee which is associated to a registration..

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would order by the person's last name, assuming you have all your ActiveRecord associations set up correctly.

```
event_registrations = EventRegistrations.find(:all)

ordered_event_registrations = event_registrations.sort{|registration_a,registration_b|registration_a.people.lastname<=>registration_b.people.lastname}
```

Comment: This would have very poor performance. Additionally `.find(:all)` is deprecated syntax.

Comment: Are you referring the fact that ActiveRecord would issue a separate select for each event_registration object?  Thats very true, but you could always load related records before hand to mitigate the problem.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html - See the section on eager loading.

Comment: The n+1 query problem is certainly part of it. Also, this is loading an awful lot of objects into memory (at least potentially). Sorting in the database would be far, far faster.

Comment: There's the n+1 issue you mention, as well as finding all records, which is unbounded and could potentially load millions of records into memory.

Comment: `EventRegistrations.joins(:people).order('people.last_name')` <- My suggestion to do this.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you have the following models and associations:

```
Event
  has_many :event_registrations

EventAttendee
  belongs_to :event_registration
  belongs_to :person

Person
  has_many :event_registrations
  has_many :event_attendees

EventRegistration
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :event
```

Now, as to your actual question. You say you want to 'order all the people related to an event'

I don't actually see how 'ordering' (a.k.a sorting) enters into this.

To get all users associated with an event, I recommend adding some :through associations:

```
Event
  has_many :event_attendees, :through => :event_registrations
  has_many :people, :through => :event_attendees
```

Then, when you have an event object, you can simply call `.people` on it, and it'll just work.

Comment: You can take this a step further, and add an ordering to the call - `@event.people.order('some ordering criteria')` and let the db do the work.

Comment: @x1a4 Indeed. I couldn't figure out what the question wanted the results sorted by, so I didn't include that.